# Trying to write a logic in Karate DSL where, I need a date in yyyy-mm-dd format. If day is Saturday then 2 day should get added to the current date

Tags: java, karate

Trying to write a logic in Karate DSL where, I need a date in yyyy-mm-dd format. If day is Saturday then 2 day should get added to the current date, 1 day if the day Sunday. Here is something that I'm trying but it is not working.

```
    * def logic =
      """
      function() {
  var date =  function() {
  var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
  var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  return sdf.format(new java.util.Date());
  }
  var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
  var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('EEEE');
  var day =  sdf.format(new java.util.Date());
  var c = Java.type('java.util.Calendar');
  if (day== 'Saturday')
  return Calendar.add(date(),2);

  }
  """
```

Comment: In what way not working? Please paste any error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using the modern API:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Current date
        // Change the JVM's default ZoneId as applicable e.g. ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        if (date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)
            date = date.plusDays(2);
        else if (date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)
            date = date.plusDays(1);

        System.out.println(date);

        // Print day name
        System.out.println(date.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-10
Monday
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>